# Verilog null/invalid slice ranges in unreachable evaluations

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Sometimes a situation comes up in parameterized code where I want to check against an array slice iff the width of that slice is non zero. I might write something like this:

```
parameter SLICE_WIDTH;
parameter SLICE_BASE;
logic [my_array_size : 0] my_array;
//...
always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
   if (SLICE_WIDTH==0 || my_array[SLICE_BASE+:SLICE_WIDTH]==0) begin
   //alternately "if (SLICE_WIDTH==0 || my_array[SLICE_WIDTH+SLICE_BASE-1:SLICE_BASE]==0) begin"
      //do something
   end
   else begin
      //do something else
   end
end
```

This was the way I handled these situations when writing VHDL; relying on short circuiting in the constant evaluations to prevent the invalid array range from ever being evaluated. In system verilog as written, this throws up "range of part select is reversed" errors and "range width cannot be zero" errors in QuestaSim.

Is there a way to cleanly deal with null ranges that most tools accept without duplicating the contents of `//do something` into several if-generate constructs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a masking parameter

```
parameter SLICE_WIDTH;
parameter SLICE_BASE;
localparam logic [my_array_size : 0] MASK) = 2**SLICE_WIDTH - 1 << SLICE_BASE;
logic [my_array_size : 0] my_array;
//...
always_ff @ (posedge clk)
   if (my_array&MASK) begin
      //do something
   end
   else begin
      //do something else
   end
```

Synthesis tools will optimize logic away when MASK is 0.

Didn't test this, so you might have to play with my equation.

Comment: I was able to use a variation of masking for this instance, although it is a pity that there isn't a cleaner general case. I suppose I could use a generate to combinationally condense the condition into an intermediate net without cloning many lines of sequential logic.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way for handling it in verilog is 'generate' blocks.

```
parameter SLICE_WIDTH;
parameter SLICE_BASE;

logic [my_array_size : 0] my_array;
//...

// generate
if (SLICE_WIDTH==0) begin
    // do something here
end
else begin
   always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
      if ( my_array[SLICE_BASE+:SLICE_WIDTH]==0) begin
         //do something
      end
      else begin
         //do something else
      end
   end
end // endgenerate
```

With SV you do not need to use the generate/endgenerate keywords.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a solution that didn't involve replicating the *do something* blocks of code.

Comment: This solution is the only clean and proven way to solve such issues in verilog. The rest are just hacks and tricks which might work in some specific cases.